# Extract ckeditor text to a new div - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use CKEditor for get some text. I also want to show how it is seen with mobile. So I created mobile screen.
This is my ClassicEditor

```
ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#kuran'))
            .then(editor => {
                function updatePhoneScreen() {

                    let kuranText = editor.getData();

                    console.log('kuranText:', kuranText);

                    let customTextContainer = document.getElementById('customTextContainer');

                    customTextContainer.innerHTML = kuranText;

                    console.log('customTextContainer:', customTextContainer);
                }
                editor.model.document.on('change:data', updatePhoneScreen);

                updatePhoneScreen();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('CK Editor yüklenirken bir hata oluştu:', error);
            });
```

And this is my div

```
                                <div class="phone-container">
                                    <div class="custom-text-container" id="customTextContainer"></div>
                                </div>
```

Actually the user write here for Quran, so this div must start from right.

Style:

```
.custom-text-container {
            width: 260px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            border: 10px solid #333;
            border-radius: 30px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-size: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: flex-start;
            color: #c82333;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 5px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            text-align: right;
            writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
            direction: rtl;  
            unicode-bidi: embed; 
            word-wrap: break-word;  
        }
```

I want to show exactly what it looks like.

One of the problem is when I press enter and go next line, mobile screen just space one word.

When I write some text:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNPHD.png)

This is console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sztKX.png)

I tried a lot of things, such as importing it with innerText instead of importing it with innerHTML and changing the place of "

" and "&nbsp", but I thought it wouldn't make sense.

I also look another answers but I'm new at this field.